# Tkinter hangs while sensing (in a for loop)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi, proximitysensor

```
while True:
    x = []

    while True:
        sense = 0
        for i in range(0,4):
            k = gpio.input(sensor)
            if k = 1:
                sense += 1
                time.sleep(.005)
        if sense == 0:
            x = abc()
```

the above code snippet is for a GUI i've made using 'Tkinter' that has a couple of buttons (Executed on, System : Raspberry Pi; OS : Fedora). one is get a sensor running and the second,  to sense if an object is present. when the sensor (active low) senses an object for more than 20 mills (after the second button is pressed) it is to execute abc() (which is a computation related to the list x). 
"the code without the GUI part works just fine" but hangs when the GUI is introduced!
could someone please point out to any potential mistake in this block of code? 
ive gone through a few questions posted here and have done a few changes to check which part of the complete code makes the GUI hang, and kind of narrowed it down to this part

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops constantly running (but I don't think the first one is not necessary, since you never break the second one) and a call to `time.sleep`. If you run this code on the Tkinter thread, the GUI will be unresponsive because the thread is "busy", constantly executing this loops.

You can execute this on a different thread and communicate, or even better, rewrite it so you can call `Tk.after` periodically (instead of `time.sleep`) to retrieve the value of the sensor and then update the content of the GUI.